# How to pass mongodb match conditions from node.js URL parameters

Tags: node.js, express, node-mongodb-native

I have a webpage where users selects variables to filter and get database values. I tried passing the $match condition variables as below but i am not getting any results back

URL is : example.com?gender=M&date_from=20100101&date_to=201140101

I loop through the req.query to build the match condition string.

```
var matchQuery = [];
for (var param in req.query) {
    qString = "{'" + param + "' : '" + req.query[param] + "'}";
    matchQuery.push(qString);              
}
var strmatchQuery = matchQuery.toString();
```

This outputs strmatchQuery as {'gender' :  'M'}, {'date_from' :  '20100101'}, {'date_to' :  '20140101'}

and then I call the mongodb aggregate function

```
dbmodel.aggregate( { $match: { $and: [ strmatchQuery ]} } , { $group : { _id : "$orderyear", totalorders : { $sum : 1 } } } )
```

But I dont get any results back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function is_numeric(num) {
    return !isNaN(num);
}

var matchQuery = [];
var qString = {};
for (var param in req.query) {
    // You need objects in your query not strings so push objects
    qString = {};
    qString[param] = is_numeric(req.query[param]) ? Number(req.query[param]) : req.query[param];
    matchQuery.push(qString);              
}

// Removed the toString() function call

dbmodel.aggregate(
    {$match: {$and: strmatchQuery}}, // Removed the array [ ] 
    {$group: {
        _id: "$orderyear",
        totalorders: {$sum: 1}}
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. It mostly works. It works when query is a string field, but date_from and date_to are numeric in my database, I guess thats causing it null result. How can I set the object value to numeric?